# How can I convert BLOB Buffer to Base64 string in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, blob, alamofire

I store a base64 string as a BLOB in swift but I can't figure out how to turn the blob buffered returned back into a UIImage.

Here is how I store it and Blob converts it into buffer.

```
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "instagramLogo.png")!
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let parameters = [
        "image": base64String
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the base64 string back to data and then init an image from Data

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: nil)
if let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!) {
    imageTypeOfCar?.image = decodedImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the conversions that you made, like this:

```
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: [])
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

Comment: This would work but I first need to convert the byte array to base64string

Comment: My API returns the BLOB as a byte array